# Repairable touchscreen laptop/hybrid under $500

Tags: laptop

1. Touch Screen
2. Full HD
3. Big screen preferable
4. i5-i7
5. SSD or SSD + HD or hybrid
6. Budget is $500
7. Surface pro "like" but something made not by microsoft. Tablet laptop hybrid kind of thing.
8. Easy to fix when broken.
9. No need for video card or minimal one. Not for gaming

Basically like the surface pro. However, I think I want a bigger space and something that I can fix more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dell's [Inspiron 2-in-1](https://www.dell.com/koa/search?q=inspiron%202-in-1#q=inspiron%202-in-1), Lenovo's [ThinkPad S1 Yoga](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Lenovo%20Thinkpad%20S1%20Yoga%20Touchscreen%20Laptop%2C%20Intel%20Core%20i5&ref=nb_sb_noss), and some HP Touchscreen PCs are the only major competition to the Microsoft Surface devices, but none of their i5 or i7 machines will fit in your budget.

Comment: Around $500 is fine. $600 is fine